# Android - take picture on paused preview

Tags: android, camera

I have a camera preview that I have successfully been able to take pictures from using  `Camera.takePicture()`.
However now I am adding a separate option to pause the preview on demand currently by simply calling `camera.stopPreview()` However I still want be able to capture what is on the screen (but not my controls, buttons etc).
Is there anyway of doing that or another way `to pause/freeze the camera`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can save the data returned in each call of the preview callback.

```
PreviewCallback pcb = new PreviewCallback() {
    public void onPreviewFrame(byte[] data, Camera arg1) {
        bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data, 0, data.length);
        //bitmap is a static Bitmap
    }
}
```

I don't know how much this will affect the frame rate before you call  `stopPreview()`.

After the `stopPreview()` call, bitmap contains the last frame that was captured.